# What is the easiest way to "recycle" tasks in Amazon ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Given a service running in ECS with, say, 2 tasks, I want to launch a new version of the underlying image. If I create a new version of the task, and update the service to use the new defition, it will launch 2 new tasks with the new version, wait for those to become healthy, and then deregister the old tasks.

This is all fine, but it means that I'm creating a bunch of task definitions that are identical, since the image name hasn't changed (it's `myapplication:latest`). And, experimentation has suggested that if I manually stop a task, and let ECS relaunch it, it will use the updated image. However, manually stopping the task causes it to become deregistered immediately, before a replacement has been launched, which means a short period of downtime.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to relaunch the images from the console. Is there any way from the CLI? Or, some other trick I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

There are no tricks here - the right way to launch a new version of task (running as a service) is to register a new task definition then update the service to point to that new definition.  Remember your image lives within the task definition, which lives in the task, which lives within the service.

The easiest way:

1. Register a new task definition (eg `register-task-definition` via the CLI).  AWS will register a new definition even if nothing has changed within your definition file.
2. Update the service pointing to the same task, but leave *off* the task revision number.  AWS will then restart two new services, wait for them to come online, then stop the two old tasks using the old definition.
3. Deregister your old task (optional).  You *can* have existing services running that point to deregistered task definitions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this in very simple way is to have your image updated with tag you want and then just do `force-new-deployment`, this will do rolling update if your cluster is configured that way.

`aws ecs update-service --cluster ${CLUSTER} --service ${SVC} --force-new-deployment --region=${REGION}`

This will avoid clutter of task-definitions (or atleast switching between blue and green and keeping track of it)

Additionally we have also automated image update before rolling restart using below

```
ECR_REPO_NAME=${1}
STAGE_TAG=${2:-"pre-release"}
PROD_TAG=${3:-"prod-ready"}

MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --region us-east-2 --repository-name ${ECR_REPO_NAME} --image-ids imageTag=${STAGE_TAG} --output text --query images[].imageManifest) 
aws ecr put-image --repository-name ${ECR_REPO_NAME} --image-tag "${PROD_TAG}" --image-manifest "${MANIFEST}"
```